# creating a PDF via google apps script but creates the PDF with an additional blank page

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a apps script bound to a spreadsheet that creates a pdf file from the sheet. this creates one single page pdf and saves it in a folder in drive. Up until recently, this worked perfectly. Now every time I run the code it does what it is supposed to but the file has a second page that is blank. When I create the pdf manually via file/download as/pdf doc, it creates the pdf as it should, with only one page. I have tried this with both the original and copy that the script temporarily creates. Both work when done manually. I am looking for some suggestions on what could have gone wrong and what to change. Here is an example of the code:

```
function makePDF() {

  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('eTimesheet');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Time Sheet');
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
  var triggercell3 = sheet1.getRange('M33').getValue();

  if (triggercell3 == 'GO'){


  var techNumber = sheet3.getRange('B5').getValue();
  var date = sheet3.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var fileID = sheet3.getRange('B7').getValue(); 
  var pdfName = "TimeSheet- "+ techNumber + " " + date

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fileID);

  sheet2.showSheet();
  sheet1.hideSheet();
//Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

//save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true); 

  sheet1.showSheet();
  sheet2.hideSheet();
  sheet1.getRange('M33').clearContent();

  }
}
```

thanks for any assistance...

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, first question I have is... if you delete a few rows from the sheet and run the script, are you back to 1 page?

I am asking in case the issue is just margin settings.  If this is the issue, maybe you can adjust rows or use the **UrlFetchApp.fetch** approach as PDF page formatting can be specified (eg: margin size).

Comment: I have tried changing the margins. The problem still exists. I am not sure what has changed because I have been running this for a while and it always generated a single page as I wanted. I did not change anything on the sheet that is being affected.

Comment: Might have been some changes on how google is handling .getAs PDF.  Did you try deleting a bunch of rows as well (just to prove even a clearly smaller sheet ends up printing and extra blank page.  If this fixes the issue, I would be happy to share some code examples that allow setting page size, scaling, and margins for the PDF.

Comment: Good example here: http://www.andrewroberts.net/2017/03/apps-script-create-pdf-multi-sheet-google-sheet/.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I deleted the sheet and copied in a fresh one and it works fine now.